# Why is location.hostname not consistent?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a asp.net MVC project, and in one of my javascripts, I am calling `location.hostname`

When I host my application on MVC, on my Windows 7 & 8 PCs, I am able to get it to print out `localhost/MyApp`

However, when I hosted this on a windows server 2008 R2 PC, it only printed out `localhost` without my virtual directory name

Why is that? and how can I get it to display my full URL?

Comment: I guess [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/93202dc4-3b30-4a72-a301-d5d5d206fd14#b2725196-e2ce-49c4-981b-995d6d3aa820) article is related. Anyway you can get full URL through `location.href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use:

```
window.location.href
```

or

```
window.document.documentURI
```